# Laravel 5.3 hasManyThrough through an intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following table relationship:

```
organizations
  id - integer

organization_users
  organization_id - integer (FK)
  user_id - integer (FK)

users
  id - integer
```

I am trying to get all the users of an organization through eloquent relationships. Here is my Organization.php model with its relationships:

```
class Organization extends Model
{
  public function Users(){
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\OrganizationUser',
                                   'organization_id', 'user_id', 'id');
...
}
```

I have tried many combinations of that relationship such as

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\OrganizationUser',
                                   'user_id', 'organization_id', 'id');
```

But all turn up somewhat the same error (this one is from the first query):

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
 found: 1054 Unknown column 'organization_users.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select
 `users`.*, `organization_users`.`organization_id` from `users` inner join 
`organization_users` on `organization_users`.`id` = `users`.`user_id` where 
`organization_users`.`organization_id` = 1)'
```

Is it possible that I can have the relationship retrieve the user_id to query on the users table instead of Laravel trying to retrieve organization_users.id? If not is there another way around this?

Comment: Your scenario is many-to-many relationship. `hasManyThrough` is used on accessing distance relationship, such as in the scenario of "organization has many users, and users has many posts, and so you can do organization `hasManyThrough` posts to access posts from organizations indirectly from users.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

**User Model:**

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Organization','organization_users');
}
```

**Organization Model:**

```
  public function users()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','organization_users');
   }
```

To, get all the users with their organizations:

```
$users=User::with('organizations')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   print_r($user->name);
   foreach($user->organizations as $organization)
   {
     print_r($organization->name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to describe many to many relationship. Thank you for pointing that out. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks like it may be a 'Many-to-Many' relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many